# Autoscroll to div in jquery .load site

Tags: jquery, autoscroll

I am loading a website in a div like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('#pagecontainer').load('http://www.example.com' );
    })
</script>       

<div id="pagecontainer" /></div>
```

The loaded site contains a DIV with id="test".
So far so good.

But would it be possible to autoscroll the page to that DIV?

The code below is not working, i think because it cant locate the DIV in the loaded site.

```
$(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#test').offset().top
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From jQuery doc:

> .load( url [, data ] [, complete ] ):
>
> where: complete
>
> Type: Function( String responseText, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
>
> A callback function that is executed when the request completes.

That means you can change the code into:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#pagecontainer').load('http://www.example.com', function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#test').offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
})
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you for the fast respons!

Comment: The loading of the site in the div is not working in jsfiddle for some reason. But i think you see what i am trying.   In the loaded site i try to hide #home  (the logo in the left top)

https://jsfiddle.net/kzsww5no/

Comment: @Maxcim First: please delete your previous comment. It's forbidden to have so much comments..... Second. I updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kzsww5no/3/). Instead of load I used append() in order to simulate your problem. If I change the media queries in the fiddle the style for #home is applied according to the max-width directive. You may test by yourself and let me know. It's late for me. See tomorrow. Let me know.  Thanks

Comment: I am verry sorry, i found the problem!  My styles looked like this:
#wrapper .container. {}  The body tag had the id wrapper. But when i load the site in the div the body tag is not loaded for some reason.  You answers helped me find it so thank you! Good night!

Comment: Back to the scrolling :)   Your solution worked, but: